# Chances of rolling a 1 on any two/three consecutive dice rolls

Tags: probability

If I roll a 1d6, it has 1/6 changes of rolling a 1. What are the chances of rolling a 1 if I roll the 1d6 two or three times in a row? On either roll.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean? The probability of rolling 3d6 and showing one 1 is different than the probability of rolling 3d6 and showing two 1s is different than the probability of rolling 3d6 and showing three 1s. Likewise, it's different from rolling a d6 *until* a certain number of 1s are shown. Are you asking about one of these events or a different event?

Comment: This is a simplified version of a question with an important history, [de Méré's Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/deMeresProblem.html).

Answer (score 1):

The chance of *at least one one* is one minus the chance of *no ones*.

If you roll one die, you have a chance of $\frac{5}{6}$ to *not* roll a one.

Die rolls are independent. Therefore, chances multiply: the chance of rolling *no one* on two rolls is $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2$, on three rolls $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3$.

Therefore, the chance you are looking for is

$$ 1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^k$$

for $k\in\{2,3\}$, the number of rolls.